# Gitlab Merge request events not triggering Jenkins Multi-branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks, multibranch-pipeline

I'm trying to trigger Jenkins Multi-branch pipeline job with GitLab Webhook on Merge request events.

When I'm testing the Webhook, I'm getting this message:

> Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 409

When I'm setting different GitLab Webhook, like Tag push events, it works.

Is GitLab Merge request events Webhook not supported with Jenkins multi-branch pipeline? Am i missing something?

If it's not supported, does anyone have workaround for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#git-configuration-for-multibranch-pipelineworkflow-jobs

Yeah, the readme notes that this functionality is not supported. Merge Events are just ignored as of now.

In this thread a user suggests some plugins that may add this support. I have not tried them myself and can not vouch.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/416

Comment: the ticket has been resolved, the recommendation is to move to another pulgin: GitLab Branch Source