# Gitlab webhook does not trigger a build on jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I've a group of multibranch pipeline jobs generated with the following piece groovy script:

```
[
      'repo1',
      'repo2',
].each { service ->

  multibranchPipelineJob(service) {

    displayName(service)

    branchSources {
      git {
        remote("git@gitlab.com:whatever/${service}.git")
        credentialsId('gitlab-ssh-key')
      }
    }

    orphanedItemStrategy {
      discardOldItems {
        daysToKeep(0)
        numToKeep(30)
      }
    }

    triggers {
      periodic(5)
    }

  }
}
```

and in each repo a `Jenkinsfile` that looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

properties([
      gitLabConnection('ci@gitlab.com'),
      pipelineTriggers([
            [
                  $class               : 'GitLabPushTrigger',
                  triggerOnPush        : true,
                  triggerOnMergeRequest: true,
            ]
      ]),
      disableConcurrentBuilds(),
      overrideIndexTriggers(false)
])

node {

  def sbtHome = tool name: 'sbt-0.13.15', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder\$SbtInstallation'

  stage('Checkout') {
    checkout scm
  }

  stage('Build') {
    sh "'${sbtHome}/bin/sbt' clean compile"
  }

  stage('Test') {
    sh "'${sbtHome}/bin/sbt' test"
  }

  if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop' || env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
    stage('Publish') {
      sh "'${sbtHome}/bin/sbt' publish"
    }
  }
}
```

It all works correctly. The *seeder* project generates all the folders from the first script and all the branches for given repo are built correctly.

Unfortunately I've problems with triggering a build for any branch after commit + push has been made to gitlab.

I've jenkins configured correctly - I mean the gitlab plugin, there is a connection and it all works well.

I've also added a webhook on the gitlab side and it also runs correctly. After a test push is sent I receive `200 OK` from jenkins and I do see in logs that scanning the branches has started and detected the changes correctly. Unfortunately the build for the changed branch does not start. Here's an extract from branch scan log:

```
  Checking branch ci
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
Changes detected: ci (a7b9ae2f930b0b10d52bb42f1ecf96a68bba4a30 → 39a4c1a65051d5e90079feec14ad22455a77c58e)
Did not schedule build for branch: ci
```

I'm 100% sure that this not a problem with communication between my jenkins instance and gitlab account. I see the webhook being triggered after push to gitlab, I see the request being send and branch scan being run. Changes are also detected but **why on earth the job isn't started?** I've also read the [docs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#pipeline-multibranch-jobs-1) thoroughly and have it all configured correctly.

```
Jenkins version: 2.150.3
Gitlab version: 11.8.1-ee
```

**EDIT**

It seems that after upgrading jenkins to v.2.164.1 it all started working correctly.

Comment: What version of Gitlab-plugin do you have in Jenkins? With jenkins version 2.1.60, gitlab plugin 1.5.11 and gitlab version 11.6.3-ce your DSL creates the multibranch job and the branch is built when pushing. Try to create one of the repos with Open Blue Ocean plugin and see what happens. By the way check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914104/gitlab-merge-request-events-not-triggering-jenkins-multi-branch-pipeline. It seems merge requests are not supported by the plugin yet.

Comment: There is an open MR to allow MR for multibranch pipelines https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/pull/857

Comment: Could you share also your GitLab webhook?

Answer (score 4):

I found this very useful [Setup Example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/wiki/Setup-Example) ([Continuous Integration with Jenkins and GitLab](https://medium.com/@teeks99/continuous-integration-with-jenkins-and-gitlab-fa770c62e88a)) . Especially the part *Source Code management*:

> We need to specify the name as “origin”, which will be used by the other sections. For the Refspec we need to input:    `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*`

And also:

> Branch Specifier we need `origin/${gitlabSourceBranch}` which will be filled in based on the web hook we’ll be setting up next.

---

**Edit1**

You could try the following for one multibranch pipeline:

1. Select a branch, for example `ci`
2. Select "View Configuration"
3. Under "Build Triggers" select the checkbox "Build when a change is pushed to GitLab"
4. Make some changes to the code and push to `ci`

---

**Edit2**

I could not find a suitable git-project to run and try to reproduce this behaviour. So if someone know a similar project and could share, please comment and I could do some more testing.

For **Gitlab** (requested a trial key, [otherwise it will be a GitLab Community Edition](https://about.gitlab.com/install/ce-or-ee/)):

```
sudo docker run --detach --hostname gitlab.example.com --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 --name gitlab --restart always --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ee:11.8.1-ee.0
```

For **Jenkins**:

```
sudo docker run  -u root  --rm  -d  -p 8080:8080  -p 50000:50000  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  jenkins/jenkins:2.150.3
```

Then "**Integration**" —> "**Jenkins CI**" in Gitlab as in this image:[image]

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Unfortunately there's no "Source code management" section - is it added via any plugin?

Comment: @Opal Edited the post, could you try it ?

Comment: @Opal Okey. Just for the purpose of troubleshooting, could you setup one of the repositories as a “Freestyle” (in Jenkins) and follow the guide in my post. Then you will see the “Source Code Management” section. Thanks!

Comment: No idea if I find time, but will try.

Comment: @Opal I totally understand. I’m having trouble creating the issue you have. Do you have more example code to share or know a similar project ?

Comment: Actually not at all. All in private repositories.

Comment: @Opal Understand. I edited the post with what I tried, hopefully it might be useful for the next person to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to use [`includes()`](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/multibranchPipelineJob-branchSources-git) to specify pattern(s) identifying which branches will be included:

```
branchSources {
  git {
    remote("git@gitlab.com:whatever/${service}.git")
    credentialsId('gitlab-ssh-key')
    includes('ci')
  }
}
```

You can specify a number of patterns, which can include wildcards. For example:

```
includes("master release/* feature/* bugfix/*")
```

There is also a corresponding `excludes()` for even finer-grained control.

Comment: I've used `includes('*')` and it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you have configured [Basic Branch Build Strategies](https://github.com/jenkinsci/basic-branch-build-strategies-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc) to only include specific branches e.g. using Exact Name: `master` which would skip the branch `ci` from your example.

Ensure that your Jenkins branch build configuration covers the branches that you are testing for. Also make sure that [Suppress automatic SCM triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42823938/1602555) option is not set.

Do note that settings on Organization or Folder level will influence the specific Project and Job settings, unless they are specifically overridden on lower level.

Comment: How it can be checked?

Comment: @Opal try going to the job Configure page. If the settings are not there (SCM section?) check the containing Project, Folder, Organization and System options due to configuration inheritance.

Comment: I don't have "Basic Branch Build Strategies" plugin installed - is it required to have it set?

Comment: I've installed "Basic Branch Build Strategies" and added "Build strategies: regular branches" to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Opal can you try defining an empty trigger without schedule as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9921495/1602555) for your job and then pushing into branch?

Comment: There's no such option.

Answer (score 1):

We were facing similar (not the same) issues with gitlab and Jenkins and the problem was related with the credentials.

In Jenkins, we created a new global Access token for GitLab (Jenkins Configuration -> Credentials -> System -> New Global access -> Define a gitlab token). That generates a Token that we added it to the Webhook, now the hook being something like:

```
http://[Gitlab User]:[token ID]@Jenkins Address
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks but I doubt if lack of the token results in the failure I have. There's no problem with authentication at all.

Comment: As I said, it worked for us in a similar scenario (branch being indexed but not build triggered and not auth problem shown). Have no other hints, sorry