# Jenkins - Multibranch pipeline build on push

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I'm trying to setup a multi-branch pipeline project in Jenkins. Ideally, I would like the branch pipelines to be build once the developers push new code. For example, if a developer pushes to a 'dev' branch then the 'dev' pipeline will build automatically.

I know that under the "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers" option you can set how often Jenkins will look for changes, but I would prefer it to be the other way around, meaning that once new code is in the branch then Jenkins will build the pipeline.

[image]

I have my Jenkinsfile configured and also set the web-hook in my GitHub project, but I don't know if what I want to do can be done or if I'm missing a plugin or configuration. In addition, Jenkins is currently running as a Kubernetes pod.

Comment: You are looking for a 'webhook'. Depending on your SCM seting up one differs. Which SCM do do you use?

Comment: Based on the tags, the user seems to be using git

Comment: Hello, yes I'm using Git

Comment: Also I forgot to specify but Jenkins is running as a Kubernetes pod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw the problem, for the multi-branch pipeline project the source must be GitHub instead of Git. Configure the web-hook with the desired events, build the project manually one time and then do a test push, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install [Github Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin) on Jenkins and configure the URL to `<JENKINS_URL>/github-webhook/` for your GitHub webhook.

You can check [this support documentation](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003019232-GitHub-Webhook-Pipeline-Multibranch) from cloudbees for step by step configuration help.

Comment: I already did the webhook configuration in my repository, with content type: application/json and the events "commit comments", "pull requests" and "pushes". I forgot to specify that Jenkins is running in a pod in Kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

I shared a guide/tutorial in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55021848/10619575), it was about Gitlab and Jenkins but there are some similar parts which might help you.